# Node.js and socket.io - problems in Opera browser

Tags: node.js, opera, socket.io

I use a browser - Opera version 11.52.
I use version of the node.js - v0.4.12 and socket.io version 0.8.5.

I tried this example - https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat

This page starts up and displays only the message - Connecting to socket.io server = **In opera**.

Other browsers work properly - Firefox, IE, Chrome.

I tried to debug node.js - No errors.

Comment: What platform are you on? Same versions of Opera, node.js and socket.io are working fine for me on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following this guide: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO and configuring the transports setting to something that prioritizes xhr-polling over websockets and see if that resolves the issue. My experience with using socket.io on production web apps has been that the websocket transport is not as reliable as xhr-polling.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enable Websocket? Put in your toolbar, then check, then save.

```
opera:config#UserPrefs|EnableWebSockets
```